# Cannot remove appended elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple multi-text input with jQuery, appending text fields working fine. But, struggling to remove them. I googled, checked past questions but, don't know how to match them to my code.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    (function () {
        $('.dd').on('click', '.addRow', function () {
            i = i+1;
            var start = $('#fields'),
            newRow = $('<input type="text" name="i" class="quantity" /><p class="xx">X</p><br><br>');
            $(start).append(newRow);
        });
    })();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dd">
    <form action="js-more-fields.php" method="get">
        <div id="fields">
        </div>
        <p class="addRow">Add a Row</p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't see you're removing the element..

Comment: Oops I updated the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/87qm2j8p/

Comment: Thanks! I checked the fiddle. Why should I wrap the appending <input> with a <div> ?

Comment: Ok thanks everyone! Specially Rayan. I got it worked!!! :)

Comment: @TharinduLucky I believe Rayon added the div in order to remove the adjacent p and br elements.

Comment: Ok.. :) It's because, we click the remove button and we need to remove entire input field with along with the remove button. So we need a parent. So, parent is removed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a438h5sa/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    (function () {
        $('.dd').on('click', '.addRow', function () {
            i = i+1;
            var start = $('#fields'),
                newRow = $('<div id='+i+'><input type="text" name="i" class="quantity"/><span class="delete">X</span></div><br/>');
            $(start).append(newRow);
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
       });


    })();
    });
```

:You are trying to bind click on dynamic created element which does not exist.You can use delegate or on for doing this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with @Rayan's fiddle. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery on for dynamically created elements:

[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: this should be a comment